# What's the name of this woocommerce extension?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, content-management-system

http://188.226.173.21/takeawaywp/menu-list-view/

Whats's the name of this plugin/extension?

The important thing is that when you click on option, you can choose which sauce you want and the menu items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all in the theme TakeAway which the website is been using. It uses angular js in its code for the styling and effect of the functionality. There is no separate plugin or extension for this.

All the Products here are WooCommerce Products here are WooCommerce Product the reason here you are able to see the options is that because they are variable products.

Here are the direct links to the themes which you can refer too.

http://themeforest.net/item/takeaway-restaurant-online-food-ordering/9701608

http://themeforest.net/item/takeaway-restaurant-online-food-ordering/8719036.

Check the demo and preview for confirmation.